# How to use imap_open behind proxy?

Tags: php, curl, proxy, imap, fsockopen

I don't really know how to ask this question so I'll just ask it as best I can. Is it possible to use a proxy connection to read mail from a pop3 or imap server using PHP's `imap_open`?

I would prefer to use `imap_open` since it's so simple to handle the mail. but, if using `imap_open` isn't possible, what other solutions are there? Could CURL or `fsockopen` work? I can't seem to find any example showing a connection to pop3/imap behind a proxy in PHP.

Any advice would be very helpful!

Comment: Well, depends on the type of proxy: if it is a (transparent) sox proxy then it is just a question of configuration. If you are talking about an internet access where all outgind traffic is blocked except http via a web proxy, then obviously you cannot use phps imap extension, since it does not use http communication.

Comment: It's a http squid proxy setup on a local network. It was setup to allow external connections on the local network when traveling.

Comment: Ah, you want to access an imap server inside a local network via a proxy, ok. As far as I know there is no real solution to transport the imap protocol via http. Some threads exist in the internet, but nothing appears to offer a real solution. Though I'd say it should be possible to implement that. You would need an implementation on _both_ sides. That way you could wrap the imap stream inside http. nothing speaks against that. But I don't know of a solution out of the box.

Comment: You might want to explode options for generic http tunneling. There might be some solutions you could adapt for your purpose.

Comment: In Theory, you could use HTTP CONNECT to tunnel it (which is how HTTPS is tunneled), but I doubt it's built into the language.